# How to use reserved URI scheme "xbls:" on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to use reserved URI scheme "xbls:" (as below) to launching XBox game page, but it only shows a black screen to me, and nothing in it, could you tell me why?

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("xbls:"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to overwrite xbls url scheme? 
if so, it is not possible. Because we can't use reserved URL schemes for our own apps.

If you want to open a game using that URL scheme here then here is the scheme. 
xbls://game/?gameid=[GAME_ID]

Example URL xbls://game/?gameid=474607D1

I got this URL options from this link http://windowsphone.xbox.com/en-IN/MOW/gamesloft_publisher_sale_2013_8

I don't know how to get GAME_ID.